# Get executing assembly name from referenced DLL in C#

Tags: c#, .net

What is the best way to get the application name (i.e MyApplication.exe) of the executing assembly from a referenced class library in C#?

I need to open the application's app.config to retrieve some appSettings variables for the referenced DLL.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

If you want to get the current appdomain's config file, then all you need to do is:

`ConfigurationManager.AppSettings`....

(this requires a reference to System.Configuration of course).

To answer your question, you can do it as Ray said (or use `Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().FullName`) but I think the problem is easier solved using `ConfigurationManager`.

Comment: Will this solution work with asp.net application?  The referenced class library can be used by WinForms and ASP.NET apps

Comment: yep, that's the beauty of ConfigurationManager.  It selects whichever app.config/web.config is appropriate for the app domain.

This was introduced in .NET 2.0.

Comment: I just ran a test with an asp.net application and a WinFomrs application and it worked for both environments.  I am currently running a test with a WCF service.  This is web I was running into issues.

Comment: Is the dll you're talking about in a separate app domain?

Comment: This worked for ASP.NET and WinForms application, but it does not work for a WCF service.

Comment: @Ben - How would I figure that out?

Comment: `Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly()` does not get the assembly the OP is looking for. `Assembly.GetEntryAssembly()` does

Comment: I have  Service.Host.dll and SvcImpl.dll ( <%@ ServiceHost Service="SvcImpl"  %>). Service  Host in IIS.
This code in SvcImpl.dll:
1) Assembly.GetEntryAssembly() gets null.
2) Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly() gets SvcImpl.
3) Assembly.GetCallingAssembly(); gets System.ServiceModel.                                             
How can I get Service.Host programatically in SvcImpl if Assembly.GetEntryAssembly() gets null?

Comment: Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().FullName doesn't give Application.exe name

Answer (score 63):

To get the answer to the question title:

```
// Full-name, e.g. MyApplication, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null
string exeAssembly = Assembly.GetEntryAssembly().FullName;

// or just the "assembly name" part (e.g. "MyApplication")
string exeAssemblyName = Assembly.GetEntryAssembly().GetName().Name;
```

As mentioned by @Ben, since you mention wanting to get the configuration information, use the `ConfigurationManager` class.

Comment: That requires using System.Reflection?

Comment: Yes, that's in the System.Reflection namespace.

Comment: This was returned from that call: MyApplication, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null

Comment: To find out which is the required namespace just select in the above code the Assembly and Ctrl + Shift + F10 ...

Comment: That is so nice of you, that about two years pass and you edit your answer to include my solution. What took you so long? :P

Comment: `Assembly.GetEntryAssembly()` returns null for an ASP.net web-site. `Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly()` returns something.

Comment: AppDomain can be a EXE application, Web application, Unit test application, Addin Visual Studio, and "Silverlight App"(?). Maybe interesting full solution for all cases.

Comment: I have  Service.Host.dll and SvcImpl.dll (<%@ ServiceHost Service="SvcImpl"  %>)
Service  Host in IIS.
This code in SvcImpl.dll:
1) Assembly.GetEntryAssembly() gets null.
2) Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly() gets SvcImpl.
3) Assembly.GetCallingAssembly(); gets System.ServiceModel.

How can I get Service.Host programatically in SvcImpl if Assembly.GetEntryAssembly() gets null?

Answer (score 11):

To get the exact name without versions, etc. use:

```
string appName = Assembly.GetEntryAssembly().GetName().Name;
```

Works with .NET v1.1 and later.

Comment: If A.exe uses B.dll, and B.dll uses C.dll, what's happens if that code is in C.dll ?

Comment: Still returns A.exe, unless A.exe is unmanaged, or any of the dlls is loaded into separate AppDomain. For details see: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.assembly.getentryassembly(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: I have  Service.Host.dll and SvcImpl.dll (<%@ ServiceHost Service="SvcImpl"  %>)
Service  Host in IIS.
This code in SvcImpl.dll:
1) Assembly.GetEntryAssembly() gets null.
2) Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly() gets SvcImpl.
3) Assembly.GetCallingAssembly(); gets System.ServiceModel.

How can I get Service.Host programatically in SvcImpl if Assembly.GetEntryAssembly() gets null?

Answer (score 9):

You can get the assembly through the class type...

```
typeof(MyClass).Assembly
```

Answer (score 9):

If you want the name of the parent EXE and not the referenced DLL assembly - you will need to use this:

```
Assembly.GetEntryAssembly().GetName().Name
```

This will return the EXE name (minus the .EXE part).

Using GetExecutingAssembly() is not right as per the OP's question (first paragraph of it!) as it will return the DLL name.

Answer (score 5):

You should never couple your libraries to a consumer (in this case Web, WinForm or WCF app). If your library needs configuration settings, then GIVE it to the library.

Don't code the library to pull that data from a consumer's config file. Provide overloaded constructors for this (that's what they are for).

If you've ever looked at the `ConfigurationManager.AppSettings` object, it is simply a `NameValueCollection`. So create a constructor in your library to accept a `NameValueCollection` and have your consumer GIVE that data to the library.

```
//Library
public class MyComponent
{
  //Constructor
  public MyComponent(NameValueCollection settings)
  {
     //do something with your settings now, like assign to a local collection
  }
}

//Consumer
class Program
{
  static void Main(string[] args)
  {
    MyComponent component = new MyComponent(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to read (and display) version number:

```
  Assembly ass = System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();
  AssemblyName assname = ass.GetName();

  Version ver=assname.Version;
```

Somewhere in application (ie Title block in a Windows form)

```
 this.Text = "Your title    Version " + ver;
```

Answer (score 1):

For the short name of an assembly from a class instance:

```
Me.GetType ().Assembly.GetName().Name
```