# Getting ApplicationName

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, application-name

Can´t find a way to get my ApplicationName.
Found a static method to get and set app name but I am not sure how to use it.

Comment: Could I get this way:  SqlMembershipProvider msmp = new SqlMembershipProvider();
                string appName = msmp.ApplicationName.ToString(); ?

Comment: This should help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/272821/get-executing-assembly-name-from-referenced-dll-in-c-sharp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found a very simple way to retrieve my application name:

```
SqlMembershipProvider msmp = new SqlMembershipProvider();
string appName = msmp.ApplicationName.ToString();
```

;O)