# How to get assembly information of executable from the referenced dll?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, dll

I have a Windows WPF application which compiles to "MyApp.exe". This application references my DLL named "MyDll.dll". In DLL, I have following function:

```
public string GetFileDescription()
{
    System.Diagnostics.FileVersionInfo fileVersionInfo = System.Diagnostics.FileVersionInfo.GetVersionInfo(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location);
    return fileVersionInfo.FileDescription;
}
```

This function supposed to read file description of the executable. But, it is returning same of DLL instead.

If I copy the function to application, it just works fine. But the function should stay in DLL.

How to get assembly information of executable from the referenced dll?

## References:

I read multiple questions (including [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/909555/5779732)) on Stack Overflow but none of it involves DLL. This [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/272821/5779732) is about executable name; I want executable file description.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `Assembly.GetEntryAssembly()` rather than `Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly()` to get the entry (i.e. EXE) rather than the current (i.e. DLL).